# Biztalk: Is it possible to have multiple hosts that each host can perform its own sending, receiving and processing function?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

By reading documents on MSDN, I realized that it is recommended to create separate hosts by functionality (Sending hosts, Receiving hosts and Processing hosts). And if there is only one host in this bizTalk server, this host can perform all receiving, sending, and processing messages functionality.

My question is: Is it possible to have multiple hosts that each host can perform its own sending, receiving and processing function , and not affect each other?

This is for multiple developers working on the same project, because our current situation doesn't allow us to have a full set of SQL Server Database and SQL server for each developer or using VM.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: *Is it possible to have multiple hosts that each host can perform its own sending, receiving and processing function , and not affect each other?* Yes it is possible - that is the whole point of having separate hosts.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple hosts is not a solution for letting multiple developers work on a single server. A single send/receive adapter can only be assigned to one host.

You will also run into other problems, as all the configuration settings are shared in a single database, a change from 1 developer will effect the others.

Comment: if the database stays the same, only the programs change, is there anyway to solve the issues (like pin the address of message sending and receiving host instances).

Comment: It will only work if different developers are working on completely seperate solutions, with different adapter usage, with different projects

Answer (score 1):

This same question was asked and answered at MSDN.  What you are trying to do is not supported and will not work.  *There is no way around this.*

You must deploy the same application code to each computer in a BizTalk Group.

Sharing a BizTalk computer for development work is not a workable or productive solution and will have a definite negative affect on productivity.

You are correct, the best way to handle DEV is a VM with the entire stack.  This is the issue you must address in your environment.

Comment: It might be helpful to link to the MSDN question in particular here.

Comment: Hmmm..I might have been thinking of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26622258/biztalk-mutiple-host-instance-affecting-each-other/26623390#26623390.  But I'm pretty there was a (now deleted) thread at MSDN on the same topic.

Comment: It also means there's no way to pin the address of message sending and receiving?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what 'pin the address' could refer to.

Comment: Sorry about the late reply. It means if there are computer A,B,C which are different host instances under the same hosts. When computer A performs sending action, only computer A will receive the messages, B and C won't be affected (receive anything). In other words, if there's a sending request, pin the address of the receiving computer as required.